# request mapping POST but PUT mapped

Tags: spring-mvc, angularjs

I'm working on a spring mvc application with angularjs on the front. 
I have a simple rest service with post method for user registration (email). 
When i start the application on tomcat 7, i have this line on console :

```
INFO: Mapped "{[/mail/registration],methods=[PUT],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public void com.xtapps.schoolme.controllers.HomeController.emailReception(java.lang.String)
```

My code :

```
@Controller

public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/mail/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody void emailReception(@RequestBody String email) {
    prepareAndSendMail(email);
}
```

My web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<filter>
    <filter-name>httpPutFormFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpPutFormFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Spring</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

and my dependencies in pom.xml :

```
<spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
<javax.mail.version>1.4.7</javax.mail.version>
<jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>

 <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.mail.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

In front i call my rest service like this :

```
$http({
        url: '/rest/mail/registration',
        method: "POST",
        data: $scope.email,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
```

or like this (it's the same) :

```
    $http.post('/rest/mail/registration', $scope.email)...;
```

and i have this warning :

```
WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Do you have any idea about this problem ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The log entry says it mapped the **PUT** method. But your code shows the request method is **POST**. Does not compute!

Comment: Yes, but why is it mapped to put method ? i have only one method with post method... thank you

Comment: i'm using IntelliJ IDE

Comment: check the url. You are invoking rest/mail/registration instead of mail/registration.

Comment: in my web.xml i have  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>. All the requests are invoked with this pattern...

Comment: Even the consumes attribute in the log doesn't correspond to the decl. in code.  I think you are having a build problem - clean build, make sure the version of the file you are changing is the one that is being used at runtime (change the url & see if it reflects in the log)

Comment: Yes...effectively, it was the problem. I had classes folder in WEB-INF directory. I deleted it. But now, i haven't anymore the line "mapped  etc." on server traces. And when i call the service from angular, i have this warning : WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/rest/mail/registration] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Spring'. Thank you very much.

Comment: hello, the problem was <mvc:annotation-driven />. I forgot to add it in my servlet-context.xml. Thanks for the replies.